# Loading cloned github repo into Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to load a cloned repo off github filled with scripts and assets into a new Unity Project, however, It's proving quite difficult for me.

I have tried using ChatGPT for a bit to try and solve this problem, however, its instructions just aren't working (leading to errors, can't actually load in any script, asset, etc.)

I was expecting the route of loading all my assets into a new Unity Project to be fairly easy and straightforward, but I'm a bit stuck now.

Comment: What are you struggling with? If the cloned repo is a Unity project, you should simply be able to open the project folder. Can you give more information? Have you ensured the correct version of Unity is installed (the same that was used for the project)?

Comment: @SebastianK 
1. I am running the same Unity version between both projects. 

2. Here's the process of trying to load the files into a new project:

First, clone the master branch of my repo (holds all my game assets, scripts, etc.) into a new directory.
Next, create a new unity project to load the files in. When I look in the file explorer, there is a file type called "unitypackage" that Unity is searching for, however none of my files are of that type, and loading in files that don't match that type return an error: Failed to import package with error: Couldn't decompress package

Comment: Ah, I see. A unitypackage is a special filetype which contains a lot of data, which can then be imported, but since you don't have that (but the actual source code and assets) I'll suggest a workflow for importing into a new project in the answers.

Comment: I had errors importing actual .unitypackage files, I had to use Unity 2022 instead of 2021.3 (LTS) and copy the unpacked assets back to my project... The error was the " Couldn't decompress package"  you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Unity Hub to create a new project. Open the project in File Explorer, and copy all your source files (scripts, assets, etc.) into the `Assets` folder of the new project.

Comment: YOU ACTUAL GENIUS. Thank you so much bro. I don't know why I thought it would be so much harder than that, but it worked! Have a good day :D

Comment: Cheers, no worries! Glad to be of assistance. Great day to you too.

Comment: Here https://freefilesync.org you're welcome ^^ alternatively you can simply use a Symbolic Link so both projects "share" the very same Assets folder